# How to fix CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing with RecyclerView using the Jetpack Navigation Component? (NavigationUI)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm setting up the app navigation with the new Jetpack Navigation Component and the NavigationUI class to support navigation within a CollapsingToolbarLayout. 
However it does not work using the code/method from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#include_collapsingtoolbarlayout).

I've setted up the MainActivity as shown in the documentation:
LinearLayout as Parent View, within an AppBarLayout, within a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and the toolbar itself. And the host fragment.

The navigation start destination is a FrameLayout, which contains the actual RecyclerView.

I tried various layout_scrollFlags and tried to set a CoordinatorLayout as parent view instead of a LinearLayout.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**In the MainActivity onCreate function:**

```
// Set Toolbar as ActionBar
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

val layout = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout)
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
layout.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

**The first destination where I expect the collapsing behaviour:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             tools:context=".restaurant.RestaurantsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/restaurant_item"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I expect the toolbar collapsing while scrolling through the RecyclerView.
Actual it's just static.

I think there might be a connection between the RecyclerView and the CollapsingToolbar missing?
What am I missing?

Comment: Use Coordinatorlayout with nestedScroling view.

Comment: @HardikBambhania could you specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Use CoordinatorLayout as Parent View instead of LinearLayout. 
Remove the CollapsingToolbarLayout.
Declare *layout_scrollFlags* in the **Toolbar** (eg. app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap").
And in the fragment View add *app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"* (important since we use a RecyclerView in the home Fragment)

**main_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity onCreate**

```
    // Set Toolbar as ActionBar
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, you are my saviour. I've also struggled with this recently, so I've played around with your solution a bit more, and I've come to a few 
conclusions (time of writing 2019-08-08):

**TL;DR** CollapsingToolbarLayout works too, but fragment is sized incorrectly.

1. The top level layout must be a CoordinatorLayout, because if it wasn't nothing could coordinate the AppBarLayout and the fragment.
2. The `<fragment>` element **must** have the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. It seems that CoordinatorLayout only searches among its direct children to find a behavior.
3. It's actually fine to have a `AppBarLayout`/`CollapsingToolbarLayout`/`Toolbar` hierarchy. As long as the `<fragment>` has `app:layout_behavior` attribute, this will 
   also work fine.
4. The layout inside the fragment doesn't really matter. In my case use a viewmodel which means I need an extra `<layout>` wrapper so I've tried both

   ```
   <layout>
     <data></data>
     <FrameLayout>
       <RecyclerView/>
     <FrameLayout>
   </layout>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <layout>
     <data></data>
     <CoordinatorLayout>
       <RecyclerView/>
     <CoordinatorLayout>
   </layout>
   ```

   which both work fine. The inner CoordinatorLayout doesn't swallow the behavior because the RecyclerView doesn't have or use a behavior, but this leads me to my next point:
5. This arrangement doesn't resize the fragment properly. If you also add a FloatingActionButton to the fragment, it doesn't work with FrameLayout properly (FAB in upper left corner despite `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"`).

   If you use a CoordinatorLayout inside the fragment, like in my second example above, the FAB jumps to the right position. Showing and hiding doesn't work, even if you implement yourself a ScrollAwareFABBehavior. Instead what happens is that the FAB scrolls offscreen, showing that the fragment is 100% the vertical height of the viewport, but gets shifted down by the height of the toolbar (if it's an expanded CollapsingToolbarLayout, this could be 300dp or almost half the screen in my case).

I haven't been able to find a way around this problem and I'm going to stop trying for the time being. It seems that the single-activity/single-toolbar model isn't able to handle CoordinatorLayout things just yet. The reason the Android docs use a LinearLayout is probably to make sure the fragment has the correct vertical size, but the give up any dynamic behavior features along the way. I will probably be using nested navigation graphs going forward where each section of the app will have the appropriate toolbar contained within it.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers, please do comment. I'd like to actually get this working some day.